# Filter the List and assign to another List

Tags: c#

I have two separate lists in my code.

```
public static List<string> stringList= new List<string>();
  public static List<bool> boolList= new List<bool>();
```

I want to filter the list.

1. Filter all True (boolList)
2. Get the index (Filter index)
3. Get the string value based on that index (stringList)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var filtered = stringList.Zip(boolList, Tuple.Create)
    .Where(t => t.Item2).Select(t => t.Item1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = boolList
                .Select((x, index) => new { IsTrue = x, Index = index })
                .Where(x => x.IsTrue)
                .Select(x => stringList.ElementAtOrDefault(x.Index));
```